# Renaming a S3 file after unload and posting it to another AWS Account S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have some data which I need to dump from redshift (AWS Account A) to another S3 (AWS Account B).

My AWS Account (A) has permissions to write to the necessary S3 bucket in Account B.

The file path in Account B needs to look something like this: `s3://folder1/folder2/YYYYMMDD.gz`
where the filename will be a daily feed.

Unfortunately, when I use unload, it adds 000 to the end of the filename so it looks like `YYYYMMDD000.gz`. Due to the way Account B's pipelines are designed, I cannot let that filename be with `000`.

My solution is to unload to my account A: `s3://accountA/folder1/folder2/YYYYMMDD000.gz` and somehow move and rename the file and dump it in Account B at `s3://folder1/folder2/YYYYMMDD.gz`.

Is there a better way to achieve the same? Are there any native AWS tools which can help me move these files between accounts and rename (such that as soon as the file drops in my account, the file copy is triggered)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it still append `000` if you set `PARALLEL OFF` in the `UNLOAD` command?

Comment: Yes. I am using parallel OFF.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the file name exactly when `UNLOAD`ing from redshift. By default you cannot even control the number of files created as it depends on the amount of data and size of your Redshift cluster (number of slices). So, since Redshift is not the swiss army knife, you can use AWS api (in python using `boto3`, as bash command using `aws` cli) to move and rename the file.

I suggest you unload the file to some staging area first, and then move it to your desired location as a second step:

```
UNLOAD 
...
LOCATION s3://AccountB/staging-area/YYYYMMDD
PARALLEL OFF
```

and then

```
pip install awscli

aws s3 mv s3://AccountB/staging-area/YYYYMMDD000.gz s3://AccountB/folder1/folder2/YYYYMMDD.gz
```